# How to check if XML Data is valid for java XMLDecoder

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

We are serializing and deserializing Data with java [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [XMLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html). You can read an object like in the example provided in the javadoc of XMLDecoder:

```
XMLDecoder d = 
    new XMLDecoder(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("Test.xml")));
Object result = d.readObject();
d.close();
```

`readObject` parses the input and returns an Object, if there is one. If not it will simply throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I was wondering if there is a way to validate the contents provided to XMLDecoder (in the example above the file content of "Test.xml") in advance so the XMLDecoder can properly work with it. (I am aware set there is a setExceptionHandler Method, however this handler is only called during parsing, which is done when calling readObject). Or is there a "XMLEncoder" dtd or xsd of some sort?